# Creating a user generated list in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to create a flash application that will keep track of user generated values.  The app should basically allow the user to input the name of the item and it's cost.  The total costs should then be added up to show a total value to the user.  I can probably figure out how to add the values together, but I'm not really sure how to allow the user to create a list and then allow the user to save it.  Can anyone point me towards a tutorial or point me in the right direction?

I am using variables to add user inputed numbers to come up with a total.  The first problem is that actionscript 3.0 does not allow variables for texts.  I just converted it to 2.0 to fix this.  The second problem, is when I test the app and put in my values and click submit, I get NaN in the total values field.  Is there a reason why it wouldn't add the values?

Here is the code I used for the submit button:

on (release) {
total = Number(rent) + Number(food) + Number(travel) + Number(entertainment) + Number(bills);
}

Am I missing anything?

Can I give the input text instance names and then give them variables?  How are some ways to go about this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what fixed the issue for me in action script 3.0:

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addThem);

function addThem(e:MouseEvent)
{
    totalField.text = String ( Number(field1.text) + Number(field2.text) + ....);
}
```

I also had to name the instances appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Have an `object array`, say for example

```
var stack:Array = new Array();
```

Then push the item name and it's cost to that array when user inputs, like

```
stack.push({item:AAA, cost:xx});
```

So that you can generate the list whenever you want with that array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to see how this works in code. A list in actionscript could be stored inside an array, vector, dictionary or even an Object.

```
 Var myList:Array = [];
 myList.push({name: "item 1", cost: 5 });
 myList.push({name: "item 2", cost: 7.5 });
```

If you want to grab the 'product' of "item 1" from the list, you have to create a function for that, lets call it getProductByName

```
 function getProductByName(name:String):Object
 {
    for each(var product:Object in myList)
    {
       if (product.name === name) return product; 
    }
    return null; // no match found
 }
```

You can call that function like this:

```
 var product = getProductByName("item 1");
 trace(product.cost); // 5
```

And you can alter the product, so lets make it more expensive

```
 product.cost += 1;
 trace(product.cost); // 6
```

Have fun! If you are using classes, you would create one for the product, with public name and cost, and in that case you'de better use a vector, to ensure working with the right type.

Comment: I have added an edit to my post that might explain where I am a little better. I'm still having a little trouble understanding your post.

Thanks for the help!